# For Loop using Javascript and calculations

Tags: javascript

I have been given a mock test to complete for java script but I am having difficulty working out how to use a for loop to count through a pre-defined variable number and then taking that number to use on other equations.

This is what I need to do...

1. Multiply each of the first nine digits by a weighting factor according to its position
2. add the results of each multiplication together.
3. divide the total by 11 and establish the remainder.
4. subtract the remainder from 11 to give the check digit

starting postion is 1 - 9 and the weighting factor is 10-2 for example

SP|WF
1 | 10, 2 | 9, 3 | 8, 4 | 7, 5 | 6, 6 | 5, 7 | 4, 8 | 3, 9 | 2

this is the code I have done so far but I am kind of stuck at this point on using the for loop to count the number var instead of 1-9. I have skipped it and carried on the code which is functioning I just can't work the for loop out and also the var total part im struggling.

```
//setting variable to equal a number
var number = "4010232137"; 

//return value is set to 0 to use as a boolean so if code is false before then IF           statement not used
var returnValue = 0;

//confirming length of number so it meets reuirement of being 10 digits long
var length = n.length;

    var weightFactor = 11 - i;
    // get the "ith" character
    c = n.charAt(i);
    var result = c * weightFactor;
    var total = total + result;
    }
}

var tenthDigit = number.slice(9);
var remainder = total % 11;
var checkDigit = 11 - remainder;

if(checkDigit == 11){
    var checkDigit = 0;
}

if(checkDigit == tenthDigit){
    var returnValue = 1;
}

WScript.echo(returnValue)
}
```

Comment: can you tell me a sample in and out ? your question is a little difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple what you want to do, going step by step:

```
var number = "4010232137";
var result = 0;
var wf = 10;
```

these are your initial variables, result will contain the sum after multiplication with the weighting factor which will start from 10 and will decrease by 1 after every loop interval:

```
for(var i=0; i<number.length - 1; i++){ //multiplying first '9' digits by wf
    result += number[i]*wf;
    wf--;
}
```

this is the simple loop to multiply first 9 digits by wf and adding the sum. See how wf is being decreased by 1, so the first digit will be multiplied by 10, second by 9 and so on... In this case sum (result) will be '92'.

```
var remainder = result % 11;
var checkDigit = 11 - remainder;
```

Next up we calculated the remainder and checkDigit.

```
var tenthDigit = number[number.length-1]; //last digit
var returnValue = 0;

if(checkDigit == 11)
    checkDigit = 0;
else if(checkDigit == tenthDigit)
    returnValue = 1;
```

Then lastly your logic to compute the return value. which in this case will be 1 as checkDigit and tenthDigit are both 7.

**[Here you can find the complete working code along with results.](http://jsfiddle.net/m6ydboLr/)**

Comment: Looks brilliant thank you for your help i never thought about doing it this was as im still learning my code looks basic to yours :)

Comment: yes it was pretty basic.. you need a bit of practice to come up with your own solutions. Don't forget to vote up and mark the answer correct if it solved your problem (: